# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure on my `MFG4` server in the `user` database having 2 Sections.

First section has query like:

```
Select * From MFG4.User.Usr.EmpMast
```

And second has

```
Select * From MFG5.User.Usr.EmpMast
```

Now I have problem that when the `MFG5` server does not have the `user` database it displays an error even if it does not run first section where query is all right!!!

What should I do now???

Comment: Yikes. Don't they have sentences in India?

Comment: What do you mean by "section" ?? That's not a "normal" SQL Server construct.....  and yes - of course there will be an error if you try to run a stored procedure that isn't there..... what did **you** expect to happen??

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT * FROM [MFG4].[User].[dbo].[EmpMast]
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!